# Fleetctl uses /root/.ssh instead of remote machine using /home/core/.ssh

Tags: github, ssh, coreos, fleet, fleetctl

I cant manage to clone a private repo from a unit file. I get the Host key verification failed error message. Cloning it on the remote machine from the command line seems to work just fine.

After debugging i saw that the fleet client on the remote is looking for keys in /root/.ssh and my remote machine in /home/core/.ssh.

Any idea how to fix this?

greetings A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the user that a unit runs as with `User=core`. That should look into your home dir for the correct key. More details here: https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/registry-authentication.html#the-.dockercfg-file